# Is this code safe? Calling functions from a class that's being destroyed

Tags: c++

```
class B;
class A
{
    private:
        unsigned int x;
        B *m_pParent;

    public:
        A(B* parent) : m_pParent(parent)
        {
            x = rand();
        }

        ~A()
        {
            m_pParent->doCleanup();
        }

        unsigned int getSomeVariable()
        {
            return x;
        }
}

class B
{
    private:
        A* m_pChild;

    public:
        B()
        {
            m_pChild = new A (this);
        }

        void doCleanup()
        {
            m_pChild->getSomeVariable();
        }
}
```

In summary, class A has a bunch of cleanup code in its destructor, one of them being calling a function of class B, which has a pointer to A, to use some of A's variable get functions in the cleanup routine inside B.

Now I know that's not great design, but it's what I have to work with. I am investigating some crash logs, and it seems that this is what may be causing the crash. Could that be the case or is this code safe?

---

The object is being destroyed outside of the scope of both classes.

Comment: Where is the object being destroyed? I see a call to `new`, bit no call to `delete`.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, A is being deleted outside of the scope of both classes, which is why there is a call to B's cleanup function, so that it knows the object is being destroyed

Comment: The code you posted is safe. However, I doubt that's all the (real) code you're using, so there could still be problems with how you're really doing things.

Comment: Can't you post a testcase that reproduces the issue??

Comment: `class`-es are not destroyed (they are a compile time thing). But their instances, i.e. *objects* are destroyed!

Comment: We have a knight amongst us. Use weak and shared pointers

Comment: Thanks Ed, but I'm not about to rewrite the codebase, this is how it was created and I have to work with it.
No Lightness, it takes quite a while for the code to crash eventually, but I do have logfiles and crashdumps

Answer (score 2):

The destructor for A in your example is safe. The memory for A is not deallocated until the destructor returns, and so `m_pChild->getSomeVariable()` is OK.

*However*, your real-life code may have additional cleanup in the destructor for A that destroys members of A before `m_pParent->doCleanup()`.

For example, if the example were slightly changed, to this:

```
A(B* parent) : m_pParent(parent)
{
    x = new int(rand());
}

~A()
{
    delete x;
    m_pParent->doCleanup();
}

unsigned int getSomeVariable()
{
    return *x;
}
```

Now, the destructor for A is not safe, since `getSomeVariable` is called by `doCleanup`, and `x` is a dangling pointer at that point.

It's hard to say exactly what's causing your crash without more info. I'd recommend looking at this in the debugger, if possible. It should show you exactly where the crash happens.

Edit: You can also use Valgrind to look for memory errors on Linux, and Windows has a debug heap check you can enable.

Comment: No that doesn't happen, none of its members are destroyed before the cleanup function to the parent finishes, any pointers are deleted after the cleanup function ends and returns to the destructor, but the application crashes right before accessing a normal get variable function to a nonpointer class member variable like an int.

Comment: @SirRogers Is inheritance involved? If getSomeVariable() is defined in a derived class of A, then maybe the derived class does some cleanup that invalidates the object's state. Derived class destructors are called before the base class destructor. In any case, the code you give in the original question is safe.

Comment: There is inheritance involved, but none of the derived class' functions are called and none of its members are accessed. It's actually the derived class that triggers the destructor.

So class A : public D - D has a setDelete function, its lifecycle is managed inside an API, and that API triggers the delete call to D*, which then triggers the virtual destructor of A.

But again none of D's members are accessed neither by A nor by B, its purely A's variables and functions.

Answer (score 1):

While the destructor of a class is being executed, the object isn't destroyed yet. You can call member-functions from another class in the destructor which in turn call methods from the class being destroyed.

However, keep in mind that when you use inheritance, the sub-classes will be destroyed before the base-classes. So when the other class calls any functionality implemented in a subclass, it will run on an already destroyed object which can have unintended consequences.